# Svelte + Capacitor for build electron app - not working

Tags: electron, fs, svelte, capacitor

Getting error while building electron app with Svelte + Capacitor

```
node_modules/@types/fs-extra/index.d.ts:232:38 - error TS2694: Namespace '"fs"' has no exported member 'BaseEncodingOptions'.

232         (path: PathLike, options: fs.BaseEncodingOptions | BufferEncoding | undefined | null): Promise<string>;
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/fs-extra/index.d.ts:233:38 - error TS2694: Namespace '"fs"' has no exported member 'BufferEncodingOption'.

233         (path: PathLike, options: fs.BufferEncodingOption): Promise<Buffer>;
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/fs-extra/index.d.ts:234:38 - error TS2694: Namespace '"fs"' has no exported member 'BaseEncodingOptions'.

234         (path: PathLike, options: fs.BaseEncodingOptions | string | undefined | null): Promise<string | Buffer>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just cd to electron folder, and

```
run npm install --save @types/fs-extra@9.0.7
```

and then run

```
electron npm run electron:start
```